# Symfony - validate empty query parameter values

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, query-string

I am using the FOSRestBundle and was wondering is it possible to validate against empty query parameters using annotations?

For example when calling: `/comments/1` an exception is thrown since both `dealId` and `source` query parameters haven't been set.

However calling `/comments/1?dealId=1&source=` is fine even though the `source` value hasn't ben set and doesn't match the regex outlined in the annotation.

**Controller function:**

```
/**
 * Get a single comment.
 *
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(name="dealId", requirements="\d+", strict=true, description="The deal the comments belong to.")
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(name="source", requirements="(forum|blog)", strict=true, description="The source of the comments.")
 *
 * @Annotations\View()
 *
 * @Annotations\Get("/comments/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 *
 */
public function getCommentAction(Request $request, ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher, $id)
{
    $dealId = $paramFetcher->get('dealId');
    $source = $paramFetcher->get('source');

    // TODO: Implement


    return [ 'id' => $id, 'dealId' => $dealId, 'source' => $source ];
}
```

**Update**

I raised this issue on the FOSRestBundle's GitHub repo too and it looks as if what I am asking for is currently not possible due to the limitations of the Regex validator that is being used.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/814#issuecomment-49696288

Comment: As stated in the comment below - use allowBlank=false in the annotation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to force your parameters to be checked, you can change config file as explained in the documentation, Here is the sample:

`fos_rest: param_fetcher_listener: force`

Then you can set other options like strict, nullable accordingly.

See more details here :

[http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/configuration-reference.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20170630172452/http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/configuration-reference.html) (archive.org)
https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html#config-reference
https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/bundles/FOSRestBundle/annotations-reference.html

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `allowBlank` option of the QueryParam. In your case you would set the allowBlank to `false` to get the expected behaviour:

*The allowBlank option is NOT YET in the FOSRestBundle, but I provided a patch to the FOSRestBundle which has a good chance to land in the next release, **version 1.5.0** of the bundle.*

**This is how your Controller would look like:**

```
/**
 * Get a single comment.
 *
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(name="dealId", requirements="\d+", strict=true, description="The deal the comments belong to.")
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(name="source", requirements="(forum|blog)", strict=true, allowBlank=false, description="The source of the comments.")
 *
 * @Annotations\View()
 *
 * @Annotations\Get("/comments/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 *
 */
public function getCommentAction(Request $request, ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher, $id)
{
    $dealId = $paramFetcher->get('dealId');
    $source = $paramFetcher->get('source'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Annotations\QueryParam expects a `nullable` parameter to be set (true or false) if the `strict` parameter is used. Try setting it.

I guess you want:

```
@Annotations\QueryParam(name="dealId", requirements="\d+", strict=true, nullable=false, description="The deal the comments belong to.")
@Annotations\QueryParam(name="source", requirements="(forum|blog)", strict=true, nullable=false, description="The source of the comments.")
```

Also read more about QueryParam in the [docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md#param-fetcher-listener).

Comment: Alas having the `nullable` parameter to be set doesn't fix the issue and passing through e.g. `..&source=` passes when it should fail :(

Comment: First things first: do you still have the exception?

Comment: There is no exception thrown. It just goes through as if it was valid ouputting the result of `return [ 'id' => $id, 'dealId' => $dealId, 'source' => $source ];`

Comment: When calling `/comments/1` I mean. Was that a problem for you? You didn't specify that.

Comment: When calling `/comments/1` an exception is thrown stating that the two parameters must be provided. However if calling with for example `/comments/1?dealId=1&source=` or `/comments/1?dealId=&source=forum`it still goes through as if it was valid. Setting nullable to force doesn't change anything which for me feels like it should :(

Comment: Setting `nullable` ok but with which value?

Comment: I've tried with both `true` and `false` to no avail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57511/discussion-between-malachi-and-dlondero).

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is allowing `source` and `dealId` to be empty but I think it's possible by 
adding these parameters to your route (so they must be specified in order to access the controller) and using a string prefix  for each parameter (i.e. `dealid_` and `source_`), so it's possible to specify an empty value.

You'll also need to modify the regex requirements to allow empty values.

```
/**
 * Get a single comment.
 *
 * @Annotations\View()
 * @Annotations\Get("/comments/{id}/dealid_{dealId}/source_{source}", 
 *    requirements={"id" = "\d+", "dealId" = "\d*", "source" = "(forum|blog)*"})
 */
public function getCommentAction(Request $request, 
    ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher, $id, $dealId, $source) 
{
    return [ 'id' => $id, 'dealId' => $dealId, 'source' => $source ];
}
```

Comment: Neither of them must be empty, they must be both provided.

Comment: @Malachi if I understand correctly, they must be specified but they may be specified as the empty string

Answer (score -3):

I am not familiar with symfony, but I think a simple

```
$dealId = isset($dealId) ? $dealId : '';
```

Would help your problem

Comment: I really want to have it done within the annotations and it must be something the framework allows.

Comment: Unfortunately it will not help even without framework. It was a solution when GET params were converted to global variables (_can be configured in php.ini_), but not in any other case. And testing like `isset($_GET['param'])` with Symfony is also not a good practice. Symfony has `Request` object for dealing with request params, but OP wants to manage it using FOS Bundle **annotations**. And if you announced variable above it will be definitely `isset()` unless _NULL_.

Comment: This is not only unrelated to the topic but also a bad practice which wouldn't even work with PHP > 5.2.